# Birth certificate does not have a name for Change of Status Greencard

Tags: greencard, birth-certificate

My birth certificate from India does not have my name on it. In certain cultures they do not name the kid until later. Hence this case. How can this be taken care of for any immigration purpose?

Comment: How do you take care of it for domestic purposes?  In other words, suppose you were using it to apply for a passport; how would you connect yourself with your adult name to that document?

Comment: Why do you need a birth certificate?

Comment: OP has not returned to clarify questions.